# How can I generate a link/route/path in Roda?

Tags: ruby, rack, roda

How can I generate a path or URL in a view in Roda?

Will I need to use a plugin? If not, how else? Or will I have to hard-code urls/paths?

In Rails I'd do this way:

```
<%= home_about_path %>
```

Answer (score 3):

To just generate urls based on set semantics, you want the [path plugin](http://roda.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Roda/RodaPlugins/Path.html).

Usage looks something like this:

```
App < Roda
  plugin :path

  path :post do |post|
    "/blog/#{post.id}"
  end
end
```

And then, in your templates similarly to how you would use `something_path` in Rails:

```
<a href="<%= post_path(@post) %>" class="btn"><%= @post.title %></a>
```

Comment: I guess you can return <a> tag directly from path block instead.